# Rails routes block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have rails 2 routes in namespace 'Admin'

```
admin.resources :orders do |order|
  order.resources :attachments, :only => [:show, :destroy]
end
```

---

How to convert it to rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
resources :orders do
  resources :attachments, only: [:show, :destroy]
end
```